# Bukkit setItemStackName not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Hey I am trying to make a gamemodeGUI plugin and change the item name to make it customised.

It works but it changes the **first** block in the inventory to **white stained glass which says cancel**.

Here is my inventory and StackName code

```
    public static Inventory myInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "GamemodeGUI");

static {
    myInventory.setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BLOCK, 1)); //Survival
    myInventory.setItem(1, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK, 1)); //Creative
    myInventory.setItem(2, new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_BLOCK, 1)); //Adventure
    myInventory.setItem(3, new ItemStack(Material.LAPIS_BLOCK, 1)); //Spectator

    myInventory.setItem(8, new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS, 1)); //Cancel

    ItemStack iron = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BLOCK, 1);
    ItemStack diamond = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK, 1);
    ItemStack gold = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_BLOCK, 1);
    ItemStack lapis = new ItemStack(Material.LAPIS_BLOCK, 1);
    ItemStack cancel = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS, 1);

    setItemStackName(iron, "Survival");
    myInventory.setItem(0, iron);

    setItemStackName(diamond, "Creative");
    myInventory.setItem(0, diamond);

    setItemStackName(gold, "Adventure");
    myInventory.setItem(0, gold);

    setItemStackName(lapis, "Spectator");
    myInventory.setItem(0, lapis);

    setItemStackName(cancel, "Cancel");
    myInventory.setItem(0, cancel);


}

public static void setItemStackName(ItemStack renamed, String customName) {
    ItemMeta renamedMeta = renamed.getItemMeta();
    renamedMeta.setDisplayName(customName);
    renamed.setItemMeta(renamedMeta);
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the items twice and why all in the 0 index the second time? Everything but the cancel item will be overwritten from that slot, which is the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Now you've mentioned that. it makes sense. I'll remove the first setItem and try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code:

```
setItemStackName(diamond, "Creative");
myInventory.setItem(0, diamond);

setItemStackName(gold, "Adventure");
myInventory.setItem(0, gold);

setItemStackName(lapis, "Spectator");
myInventory.setItem(0, lapis);

setItemStackName(cancel, "Cancel");
myInventory.setItem(0, cancel);
```

If we notice your inventory, you're setting all the Items to the slot 0.

If we look at a Bukkit Inventory setup, you'll see that Slot 0 is indeed the first slot:

[image]

The problem you're facing is:

1. You put a Diamond Block named "Creative" at the first slot
2. You put a Gold Block named "Gold" at the first slot (Notice that you put at slot 0 again)
3. You put a Lapis Lazulli Block named "Spectator" at the first slot (same thing again)
4. You put a Glass Pane named "Cancel" at the first slot.

If we see what's happening here, it becomes pretty clear why the item naming is failing! You're always setting the **first item** to something different. The last value is the one that will be final, so **Cancel** will be there.

---

To Fix this, you could simply set the new values to new slots. If you want all in a row, you could do

```
setItemStackName(diamond, "Creative");
myInventory.setItem(0, diamond);

setItemStackName(gold, "Adventure");
myInventory.setItem(1, gold);

setItemStackName(lapis, "Spectator");
myInventory.setItem(2, lapis);

setItemStackName(cancel, "Cancel");
myInventory.setItem(3, cancel);
```

Or any variety of this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, As soon as bcsb mentioned it I realised. Its all working and I cannot thank you enough for helping me